Identifier scope in pin constraint file
Can a lower level Verilog module instance access a pin? If it matters, I'm using Yosys.

No, it cannot. Verilog requires hierarchical design where communication between modules happen via its ports. The ports define how an interface works, i.e. input, output, bidirectional, etc. There’s no way for a module to directly access a signal outside of its port.

What module's scope is the pin constraint file in?

In most FPGA design flows using Verilog, the pin constraint file (like an XDC file for Xilinx or a QSF file for Intel) operates at the top-level module's scope. Many dev boards actually should provide this on their website or GitHub repository.

Are you saying that the names in the pin constraint file refer to ports on the top level module?

Correct. The names used in the pin constraint file must correspond to the port names declared in your top-level Verilog module. This is necessary for mapping and synthesis. If there's a mismatch between the names in the constraint file and the top-level ports, you'll likely encounter errors during implementation. The tools wouldn’t be able to find the corresponding ports to apply the constraints to.

You can sort of think of it like a header (.h) file for C++ code. If you try calling for a function without the header file, the compiler will have no idea what you’re talking about.

So, the simple clear statement of the answer is:
The names in the pin constraint file refer to ports on the top level module.
Period.
